# Scrolling carousel item to the middle of carousel with jquery anmate() scrollLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've looked everywhere but I can't find a proper answer (maybe I missed it). In my carousel, when an item is clicked, it should move, by sliding, to the middle of carousel. I'm using `animate({scrollLeft: value }, speed);` but it doesn't do any animation, but if I do `scrollTop` it works (by tweaking the css of course...). 
Why is `scrollTop: value` working and `scrollLeft: value` not working, in `animate()`?

Please check my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rKAHV/

Many thanks

Comment: Your JSFiddle does not appear to do anything..

Comment: I think that's the point @Jon

Comment: Yes I know @Jon, that's the problem. I just wanna move, for example, the last box to the middle of the carousel when it's clicked. I didn't wanna include the whole coding as it's too big. I just took a snippet of it, the one that matters.

Comment: Could it be `float: left;` on the LI elements? I think you will find `display:inline` instead of the float will release the elements to be positioned left/right.

Comment: Ah okay. Well the answer by @gillesc is correct in saying that there is currently no scrolling to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because there is no scrolling to be done, your container is as wide as all the elements together. Scrolling would be possible only if there was scrollbars (the browser would add some)

If the intention is to only move an element you could try animating them based on their left position instead.

```
animate({left: value}, speed);
```

Comment: @gillsec: but sometime the first item will be clicked and it has to move to the center. Basically any item that's clicked move to the center of the carousel whether it's the 1st, 2nd, 5th or last item.

Comment: Here, you just need to add z-index handling if you want to make sure they are on top of the current middle on. Should aim you in the right direction http://jsfiddle.net/rKAHV/7/

Comment: Thanks for your effort @gillsec: but I want a carousel, so the whole thing should scroll, not just each item. So when an item is clicked, the whole carousel moves until that item clicked is positioned in the middle. I hope this is clear this time...

Comment: Animate them all instead of just the one, calculate the offset to center the clicked one and use that to move the other too accordingly.